# How can i do to change value id when keyup on multiple input fields?

Tags: jquery, input

here's the code:

```
<input type="text" id="participant1"  name="name[1][]" value="Andi"/> </p>
<input type="text" id="idparticipant1" name="idparticipant[1][]" value="1001"/>

<input type="text" id="participant2"  name="name[2][]" value="Smith"/> </p>
<input type="text" id="idparticipant2" name="idparticipant[2][]" value="1005" />
```

here's the jquery script:

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('[id^="participant"]').keyup(function()
{
      var txt = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "blue.php",
  data: "nameparticipant=" + txt,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data)
  {
     $(this).next().val(data.d);
     //alert(data.d); 
  }
  //failure: failerEvent
});
});//keyup

 });
 </script>
```

script of blue.php

```
<?php
$nameparticipant=$_POST["nameparticipant"]);
$res = mysql_query("select * from table where upper(name) like '$nameparticipant%'");
$t=mysql_fetch_array($res);

echo"$t[nik]";
?>
```

When i keyup input name of participant other than the name "Andy", i'd like is value id changing to 0. and when i turn it over again then its value id changed to be like the beginning.

What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
var txt = $(this).val();
```

instead of

```
var txt=$( '[id^="participant"]' ).val();
```

---

remove unneccesory `<p>` tags from the code,

```
<input type="text" id="participant1"  name="name[1][]" value="Andi"/>
<input type="text" id="idparticipant1" name="idparticipant[1][]" value="1001"/>

<input type="text" id="participant2"  name="name[2][]" value="Smith"/> 
<input type="text" id="idparticipant2" name="idparticipant[2][]" value="1005" />
```

JavaScript,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "blue.php",
    data: "nameparticipant=" + txt,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
         {
            $(this).next().val(data.d); 
         }
});
```

[working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/h4wXx/)

Comment: @N4tanata: can you add more details then. in above sample `txt` will contain value of the currently focused field.

Comment: when you do above change, variable `txt` contains the value of the editing text box. isn't that you need to do?

Comment: what can i do to change value when keyup? If the name entered does not match, then the value of id is 0, but if it is inserted according to the value of the id out ??

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking, but when you enter something on text field it will automatically change the value of the textbox.if you want to get that value, in above change `txt` containing that value.

Comment: The problem is the value `idparticipant` still not change, when i keyup input `participant`. I'd like is changing to 0 when I keyup `participants` other than the name "Andy". What can i do ?

Comment: it didn't work when i put script `$.ajax({
      url: "blue.php",
      data: "nameparticipant="+txt,
      success: function(data)
      {
                          $(this).next().val(data);
                          
      }//success
     });`
The value id not change. :(

Comment: it didnt work when i put variable `txt` after `$.ajax` on `$(this).next().val(txt);`. Please Help :(

Comment: in your ajax setup, check server returning correct data, use correct data type.

Comment: i had add the script of `blue.php`. Pls see the updated question

Comment: what do you mean by value ID?

Comment: its mean value of idparticipant.

Comment: can you put alert and see response is ok`function(data){alert(data.d);}`. if you follow each steps, it should work fine unless you are not receiving data from database.

Comment: then your server is not working properly. can't help in this stage

Comment: u mean the script of `blue.php` ??

Comment: when i change `$(this).next().val(data.d);` with `alert($(this).next().val(data.d));`. Its still not running. :(. I think my db connection is correct. WHat can i do ??

Comment: i don't tell you to put `alert($(this).next().val(data.d));` i just told you to use `alert(data.d);`. if you are not reading comment properly, no point of asking questions. read and follow the comments again it will solve your problem

Comment: I had try script from above, but it didn't work. I had try `alert(data.d);` but its not working, so i try put `alert($(this).next().val(data.d));` but also not working. See my update question

Comment: remove falier event like in the updated anser. i though you know how to put it :P. remove it and try

Comment: if i put `alert(data.d);` then the exit is `undefine`. if i put `alert(data);`, then the exit is working. But when i put `$(this).next().val(data);` is not working out. :(

Comment: did you follow the steps in comments. did you remove `</p>` tags

Comment: @N4tanata: happy to heard that