# How can i do to change value id if i keyup input text not match?

Tags: jquery, input, keyup

How can i do to change value id if i keyup input text not match ? 
Here's the code :

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('[id^="participant"]').keyup(function() 
    {
        var txt = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "blue.php",
            data: "nameparticipant=" + txt,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                $(this).next().val(data.d); 
            },
            failure: failerEvent
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's php code:

```
<?php
include"connection.php";
$nameparticipant=$_POST["nameparticipant"]);
$res = mysql_query("select * from tabel where upper(name) like '$nameparticipant%'");
$t=mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo "$t[id]";
?>
```

here's the html body :

```
<input type="text" id="participant1"  name="name[1][]" value="Andi"/>
<input type="text" id="idparticipant1" name="idparticipant[1][]" value="1001"/>

<input type="text" id="participant2"  name="name[2][]" value="Smith"/>
<input type="text" id="idparticipant2" name="idparticipant[2][]" value="1005" />
```

What can i do ? Please help me :(

Comment: What does `if i keyup input text not match` mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i do to change value id when keyup on multiple input fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830127/how-can-i-do-to-change-value-id-when-keyup-on-multiple-input-fields)

Comment: Hi N4ta nata, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please make your question clearer, this will enable folks to be able to accurately answer. See How to Ask a Good Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are trying to do, but I see plenty of problems with your code.

First, `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`.  This is the content type of the data sent *to* the server.  You are not sending JSON to the server, so this line is not needed, remove it.

Second, `failure: failerEvent`.  The option is `error`, not `failure`.  It should be `error: failerEvent`.

Third, `echo "$t[id]";`.  In your AJAX call, you are saying `dataType: 'json'`, this means jQuery is expecting the server to output JSON.  I can only assume the `id` field in your database table isn't actually a JSON string.  You probably want `echo json_encode($t)`.

Answer (score 0):

please explain more what you exactly want to do, and what is your error? Also one question for you , why you use two jquery into your code? 1st jquery-1.4.js and 2nd jquery-1.3.2.min.js.